# Livy always run on local mode

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, livy

I am trying to run Pyspark (or Spark) job via Livy server with "spark.master=yarn".

**What I have done:**

1) In **spark-defaults.conf**:

```
spark.master yarn
spark.submit.deployMode client
```

2) In **livy.conf**:

```
livy.spark.master = yarn
livy.spark.deployMode = client
```

3) I send request via CURL with **"conf": {"spark.master": "yarn"}**

Example:

```
  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  localhost:8998/batches --data '{"file": "hdfs:///user/grzegorz/hello-world.py", "name": "MY", "conf": {"spark.master": "yarn"} }'
{"id":3,"state":"running","appId":null,"appInfo":{"driverLogUrl":null,"sparkUiUrl":null},"log":["stdout: ","\nstderr: "]}
```

### **And what I am always getting in logs:**

18/01/02 14:45:07.880 qtp1758624236-28 INFO BatchSession$: Creating batch session 3: [owner: null, request: [proxyUser: None, file: hdfs:///user/grzegorz/hello-world.py, name: MY, conf: *spark.master -> yarn*]]

18/01/02 14:45:07.883 qtp1758624236-28 INFO SparkProcessBuilder: Running '/usr/local/share/spark/spark-2.0.2/bin/spark-submit' '--name' 'MY' '--conf' '**spark.master=local**' 'hdfs:///user/grzegorz/hello-world.py'

I hope somebody have any ideas how to get it over. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of Livy are you using?